# shrink-option doesn't work for numpy masked arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, shrink, maskedinput

I create a numpy masked array with the shrink-option set to `False` (which should yield a full-sized mask), and then I check the size of the mask:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
x = ma.array(range(10),shrink=False)
print 'mask size = ', np.array(x.mask).size
```

which yields: `mask size = 1`, i.e., the mask is still the default (shrunk) scalar mask.

Is this a (known) bug?

*Update:*
It seems that also the option `shrink=True` does not work properly:

```
x = ma.array(range(3), mask=True, shrink=True)
x.__setmask__(ma.nomask)                    # remove the mask (should shrink now)
x.mask.size                                 # returns 3, so mask has not shrunk!
_ = x.shrink_mask()                         # enforce shrinking
x.mask.size                                 # returns 1, so only now it's OK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here: the `shrink` option flag prevents the compression of the mask in operations, not at creation. To get an explicit mask (as a boolean array full of `False`), use the `mask=False` flag at creation instead.
Nevertheless, I agree it should be considered a bug. Nice catch.

---

When no explicit mask is given, the default is `nomask`, a special value corresponding to `np.bool_(0)`: it's a numpy boolean scalar with a value of `False`, and like any numpy scalar, a `shape` of `()` and a size of 1.

Note the difference between `mask=False` and `mask=nomask`: `mask=False` will create a mask as a ndarray with the same shape as the data but full of `False` (that's a shortcut), while `mask=nomask` just tell `np.ma` that the mask is not set (which speeds up computations).

Comment: Thanks, the different behaviour of the shrink-option at array-creation vs. -operation wasn't clear to me from the documentation. Also, isn't it curious that creating an array A with `mask=nomask` results in `A.mask` yielding `False`, but expicitly setting `A.mask=False` yields something different: [False, False, ...]? :-)

Comment: It seems though that also during array _operation_, the shrink option does not work properly, see update to my question above

Answer (score 2):

Just try setting your mask (either to False or True):

```
>>> np.ma.array(range(10), mask=False, shrink=False)
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],
             mask = [False False False False False False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> np.ma.array(range(10), mask=True, shrink=False)
masked_array(data = [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --],
             mask = [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The default for the `mask` parameter is `nomask`, but apparently doesn't generate *any* mask (and thus nothing can be "unshrunk"). Note sure why it still shows a size of 1 though.

Comment: Thanks, the difference between `mask=False` and `mask=nomask` wasn't clear to me at all!